# C++ Debugging for Game of Life code

Tags: c++, debugging

Alright, I just got finished making a function for some code I'm making, which will end up to be Conway's Game of Life, but I am getting some unexpected errors.

Here is the code:
http://tinypaste.com/244cf522

The errors are:

> error: name lookup of 'q' changed for ISO 'for' scoping
>
> error: expected initializer before 'while'

Comment: Fixed the initializer error, I forgot a semicolon, still having problems with first error though.

Comment: I guess there are new rules about if you initialize a variable inside a for loop you cannot use it outside of the loop, ugh, guess I have to go debug some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of `q` is limited to the `for` loop in which it was declared; any variables that are declared in the initialisation part of a `for` loop are treated this way.

You need to change the scope of `q` to last even after the `for` loop's scope is gone. To do this, simply move

```
int q;
```

from in the `for` to above the `for` and change

```
for (int q = ...
```

to

```
for (q = ...
```

So your whole thing would look like

```
int q;
for(q=1; var2 == "Yes" && Seeds != Seeds; q++){
```

or

```
int q = 1;
for(; var2 == "Yes" && Seeds != Seeds; q++){
```

Also, this isn't a new rule :)

Comment: Weird, thanks! I ended up just making a while loop, but now I know what do if this happens again, thanks!